# Glassfish, mod_jk: Standalone instance AJP port

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ajp

I can´t find any AJP port description for a created standalone instance within glassfish.

The default AJP port seems to be 8009, but I want to run multiple servers on the same machine, so where can I find the AJP ports for the other servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The fine manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gfaad.html) explains in detail how to provision a specific network listener for AJP, and during that procedure you also set the port that's being used.  The same setting is also accessible via the Network Config --> Network Listeners configuration section in the console, where it's referred to as a JK Listener.